# JetBrains Gateway - cannot connect to remote host

Tags: ssh, pycharm

I am trying to connect to my local remote host with JetBrains PyCharm / JetBrains Gateway, but when while loading remote instance it just exits without giving a reason why it could not connect. On remote host I am running latest Ubuntu LTS, and on my client machine I am running latest NixOS Unstable.
Screenshot of the last screen, that is being shown to me.
[image: Gateway to ...]

Answer (score 0):

Turn out that when I switched from PyCharm version 2023.2 EAP to 2023.1.2 everything started to work just fine. I have no idea why version 2023.2 EAP do not work, but I do not care at this point.